# community lightning force:recordData

Tags: community-builder, production, lightning-community

I am working on creating a community application built using lightning aura components. I recently saw lightning data service although it is mentioned that LDS cannot be used in community.

I want to know if the below tags are specifically for lightning data service ?
Can these tags used in community ? Can these work in production in community.

force:recordData
force:recordEdit
force:recordPreview
force:recordView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the tags are specific to Lightning data service, others aren't.

`force:recordData` is specific to LDS

`force:recordPreview` -> Deprecated, use `force:recordData` instead

`force:recordView` Not Specific to LDS

`force:recordEdit` Not Specific to LDS

all this can be found in the [Lightning Components Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_intro.htm)

Therefore, you can use the Non specific components in a lightning component that you want to use in your lightning community.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordData.htm):

> force:recordData Provides the ability to create, read, update, and
>   delete Salesforce records in Lightning. A force:recordData component
>   defines the parameters for accessing, modifying, or creating a record
>   using Lightning Data Service.

These tags are to be used by lightning data service for providing showing,editing,creation of sobject type of  functionalities

Can these tags be used in community ?

Lightning data service is currently in beta is only available for lightning experience and salesforce1. Its **not** available for  Communities.

Read this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_considerations.htm) for more details.

> Lightning Data Service is only available in Lightning Experience and
>   Salesforce1. Using Lightning Data Service in other containers, such as
>   Lightning Components for Visualforce, Lightning Out, or Communities
>   isn’t supported. This is true even if these containers are accessed
>   inside Lightning Experience or Salesforce1, for example, a Visualforce
>   page added to Lightning Experience.